# Generating files in nodejs escape character issue

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a NestJs project where I am trying to generate js files into the CDN blob storage.
For eg I have this object:

```
{
 "prop1":"${resolvedprop1}",
 "prop2":"John's pet"
}
```

content of the generated js file should look like:

```
var metadata=()=>JSON.parse('{ "prop1":"${resolvedprop1}", "prop2":"John's pet" }')
```

Code for generation of the file:

```
function writeToCDN(metadata){
    const content = `var metadata = ()=>JSON.parse('${JSON.stringify(metadata)}')`;
    //write content string to a file in CDN BLOB.
}
```

When I load this file into the browser and execute metadata() I get an error when parsing because the single quote is not escaped.

Important note:
I can not use backtick instead of single quote inside JSON.parse since I am expecting ${} in the prop1 value.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: `should look like:`,, so it should generate invalid Javacript?..  I'm assume you mean to escape the single quote?

Comment: Assuming you meant to escape the single quote, try -> `JSON.stringify(metadata).replaceAll('\'','\\\'')`

Comment: @keith yes that's the reason I was unable to generate a valid js file. I was able to use replace all and single quotes are working fine. But when pass ```{"prop1":"${resolvedProp1}","prop2": "John\"s pet"}``` to the writeToCDN method it is failing again.